# Why can't I get concatenate my dict even after i type str or int?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
#1 /usr/bin/python

print ('Hi')
age = 4
print (age)
pi = 22/7
print (pi)
time = "2300"
print(int(time)+age) 


eten = ("Rice", "Fish", "Stew")
print ("I like eating " +(eten [0]))
print ("I like eating " +(eten [1]))
print ("I like eating " +(eten [2]))
print ("I like eating " +(eten [0]) + " and " + eten [2])   

for food in eten:
    print ("I like eating " + food )

x = 1
while x <= 3:
    x = x+1
    print (x)

dict = {}
dict["Jon"] = 23
dict["Tom"] = 24
dict["Ron"] = 28

for age in dict:
    print (age + ' is ' + int(dict))
```

I've gone online to use online debuggers and I'm not getting anywhere. I added str in front and added int and both give me errors.

Answer (score -1):

You can not concatenate Integer with String.
The best way to solve your problem is this:

```
dict = {}
dict["Jon"] = 23
dict["Tom"] = 24
dict["Ron"] = 28


for name in dict:
    print (name + ' is ' + str(dict.get(name)))
```